# Ubuntu 14.04 - problem with colors

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

For some time my Ubuntu has problem with displaying graphics.
This is how photo looks on Windows: A - https://snag.gy/TYvGdj.jpg
And here is how it looks on Ubuntu: B - https://snag.gy/GaTo2k.jpg

At the beginning I have this problem only in Opera but now is present in every browser. I checked Opera, Chromium and Firefox and in all this cases it looks as in picture B.

I am still using version 14.04 LTS. I remember that there were some minor graphics problem but not as big as now. Something has been updated, I tried to go back and I run Ubuntu with older kernel versions like 3.13.0-32 and 3.13.0-24, but browsers still display wrong colors.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Open your firefox,input `about:config` into address bar。

found `gfx.color_management.mode`

set the value of `0`, Disable color management.

[the reference linking](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Gfx.color_management.enabled)

Comment: He said it happened in all of his browsers not just firefox. Could someone please -1 this post

Comment: It solved the problem in firefox. :)  I don't understand it, is it local problem which should be solved manually in all browser or is it problem with my graphic card driver?

Comment: Could you tell me how to repair Chromium?

Comment: i think maybe you should change the setting in your local color management.

Comment: Just find a key about windows chrome(http://www.marcelpatek.com/blog/2011/11/19/enabling-color-management-in-google-chrome/)

Comment: and i saw somebody use `Curve Viewer` to fix the color(https://tieba.baidu.com/p/4356659677)

Comment: Wow, thanks, but I don't understand why I have to do it manually, why it does not work automatically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59443/discussion-between-misiek777-and-turingmcc).

Comment: I don't know either. a Chinese Net Friend said maybe hardware is not at its best. need you to fix it. `Curve Viewer` can found in `Ubuntu Software Center`